# Is it worth it to switch to the Vintage Suit (10% discount on all items) every time I buy an item even though I already have the Advanced Suit?

Tags: dead-space-2

I am currently in Chapter 11 and just got the [Advanced Suit](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Suit).

**Is it worth it to switch to the [Vintage Suit](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Vintage_Suit)** (10% discount on all items in the Store) **every time I buy an item in the Store even though I already have the much better [Advanced Suit](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Suit)** (last suit in the first playthrough)**?**

I would like to know if I'm gonna be missing out on a significant amount of money if I stick with the Advanced Suit for the rest of the game, as I always stock up on ammo and other items when I encounter a Store, and after that, use the rest of my money to buy [Power Nodes](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Nodes). Or would the lack of a 10% discount by the Advanced Suit not have a significant effect on my item stocking up (i.e. I'll have enough money, anyway)?

Some of the factors I'm considering:

- (A pro for changing) There's no more need to save money to buy another expensive suit, as the Advanced Suit is the last RIG available in the first playthrough.
- (A con for changing) Changing Isaac's RIG takes time as I have to watch a long cutscene *every time* Isaac changes his RIG (one for the Vintage Suit, and another one back to the Advanced Suit)

Notes:

- I'm currently on my first playthrough (although an answer also with details for a New Game+ playthrough would be nice too).
- I'm currently playing without any DLCs, and hence, unable to use the DLC-added RIGs (to avoid having all weapons/armor unlocked at the start as detailed in [this PC Gaming Wiki article here](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Dead_Space_2#Weapons.2FArmor_Unlocked_At_Start)). I will be playing with the DLCs in my next New Game+ playthrough, so answers with details on the DLCs would be appreciated.
- I'm playing in Normal difficulty (an answer for the higher difficulty levels would be appreciated, in preparation for my next playthrough).

Comment: If the only con is watching the cutscene, why not do it for the free money then.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk The cutscene is long and has to be watched *every time* you change your RIG: one for the Vintage Suit, and another one back to the Advanced Suit. Also, I'm wondering if the money I'll be having for spending if I just keep my Advanced Suit when buying, would be enough for the succeeding levels (or with the DLCs or a New Game+ playthrough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all really depends on how well you're doing in the game.  After playing it a bunch, I don't find Hard mode very hard and I tend to fill up my inventory quickly when I'm picking up ammo for weapons I don't even have or extra health packs.  If you're doing well on Normal difficulty and have been banking a lot of large or medium med packs, then you might not need for a lot of money.  Late-game and New Game+ seem to be more about maxing out your weapons with power nodes, and at that point, I would say that switching to the Vintage Suit is a strong option.  Instead of 10 nodes at 100000 credits, you're looking at 11.  While that doesn't seem like a lot, I'll take the cool animation of him switching out suits in favor of a free node.  And when you get the advanced Vintage suit in New Game+, you get a larger discount.

It all depends on your preference and how well you're doing for money.  Ammo can be a problem, even on normal, for weapons you use a lot.  But if you cycle through ammo or start to sell a few things off (I found that selling stasis modules is very lucrative, as I didn't use stasis much in the game) you'll find money starts to flow in again.

So, for straight survival, I wouldn't switch suits.  But if you're try to max out weapons and are buying ten power nodes at a time, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no significant effects on most parts of the game at normal difficulty. But if playing a New Game+ and especially on the Zealot difficulty, switching to the vintage suit every time you buy one of the elite suits, will save you a lot of credits as the elite suits are expensive.

When you get the [Elite Vintage Suit](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Elite_Vintage_Suit) (15% discount), make sure to wear that before you buy the [Elite Advanced Suit](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Elite_Advanced_Suit).